# Pandas dataframe column average per row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in a pandas data frame called 'X' that holds an array of numbers;

```
pd.head()
Row_ID    X
1        [10,20]
2        [13]
3        [30,40]
```

I would like to take the mean of each array per row and replace it with column 'X';

```
Row_ID    X
1        [15]
2        [13]
3        [35]
```

How can I do this in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want a scalar value instead of a list or array, you could do the following:

```
df['X'] = [np.mean(x) for x in df.X]

>>> df
df
    X
0  15
1  13
2  35
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['X'] = df.apply(lambda row: [[pd.np.mean(row['X'])]], axis=1)

>>> df
        X
0  [15.0]
1  [13.0]
2  [35.0]
```